Blender 4.2: How to Enable CPU-Only Rendering in Cycles?
I'm running Blender 4.2 on my desktop without issues, but I've encountered a major problem: it seems Blender 4.2 no longer supports CPU-only rendering in Cycles, which is critical for my render farm. My farm, consisting of 196 CPU cores, is now idle because these machines don't have GPUs. Is there a workaround or a way to enable CPU-only rendering in Blender 4.2? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If by GPU you mean a dedicated GPU, that is incorrect, Blender doesn't need one, it could perfectly run on integrated GPU. But as far as I can remember it has always required some form of GPU. See the requirements. Basically you need to support the minimum OpenGL version and enough (v)RAM for the Blender version you want to run, you should be good to go. If not, we can't do much here, so you should probably open a bug ticket instead.

Hello and welcome. On BSE, it's important to focus on the technical issue rather than the frustration or business impact, as BSE is more about solving specific technical problems.  So I revised the question to keep the focus on the technical issue and asks for help in a way that aligns with BSE’s guidelines :)
